# Disabling particular cache element with EhCache

Tags: spring-mvc, ehcache

I am using xml configuration for ehcache, which looks something like below :-

```
<ehcache>

<cache name="ThumbnailCache" maxElementsInMemory="100" maxElementsOnDisk="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="100" timeToLiveSeconds="100" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />

<cache name="PDFCache" maxElementsInMemory="100" maxElementsOnDisk="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="1800" timeToLiveSeconds="1800" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />

</ehcache>
```

Now i want to disable **PDFCache** but not **ThumbnailCache**. How do i achieve this?
The ways which I have seen disables the whole ehcache as whole, I don't want to disable the whole ehCaching.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a cache by invoking `net.sf.ehcache.Cache#setDisabled`.
The possibility of doing this is controlled by `dynamicConfig` and it is enabled by default.